# How to start MAME on Raspbian Lite

Tags: raspberry-pi

I downloaded Raspbian Buster Lite for my Raspberry 3B+ board. Works fine. Now I'd like to add MAME so I type:

sudo apt-get install mame

Libraries are downloaded and MAME gets installed. However, when I type MAME at the command prompt, I immediately get an error: Segmentation fault. My guess is that the graphical interface can't boot.

I'm probably overlooking something... a missing library? Should I install something extra? What could be wrong?